# Can C++ to MATLAB code interface be executable without MATLAB installed?

Tags: c++, matlab, user-interface, interface

I have made an algorithm using MATLAB to be run at backend.
Also I have created one c++ GUI program to interact with my hardware.
I want to integrate the both codes such that MATLAB code runs at backend. How can I do this such that my single application can execute on the devices without MATLAB installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for that Matlab Compiler.

> When used along with MATLAB Compiler SDK™, you can package MATLAB
>   programs into software components for integration with other
>   programming languages. Large-scale deployment to enterprise systems is
>   supported through MATLAB Production Server™.
>
> All applications created with MATLAB Compiler use the MATLAB Runtime,
>   which enables royalty-free deployment to users who do not need MATLAB.
>   You can package the runtime with the application, or have your users
>   download it during installation.

More information is available [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html).

Matlab Compiler is not included in the base version of Matlab. You will need additional license to use it.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please tell me to do the same with java instead of c++

Comment: Your welcome. I have no experience with Java but example provided in  [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html) looks really simple

Comment: thanks for help, but even this did not work i did exact same work but in vain

Comment: What exactly didn't work? If you have some particular problem with the compiler maybe it's worth of formulating and posting another question?

Answer (score 0):

For a use case like this I would use the Matlab Coder.  Details can be found in Mathworks [documentation.](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html)

From help:

> Integrate your MATLAB algorithms as a compiled library component into other software such as a custom simulator
>
> Accelerate computationally intensive portions of your MATLAB code by generating a MATLAB executable (MEX function) that calls the compiled C/C++ code
>
> Prototype your MATLAB algorithms as a standalone executable on PCs and communicate the generated code as design specifications to your software engineers
>
> Implement and verify your MATLAB algorithms on an embedded processor